# Stop $.ajax call in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my function `fetchData` i want to get data from my client.

In the other function `stopFetchData` i want to stop the request.

Unfortunelty, `this.xhr` is undefined.

How i can use xhr.absort() to stop the request?

```
class getPostDataController {
    #ajaxApiBaseUrl = "/data/news/post";

    constructor(xhr) {
        this.xhr = xhr
    }

    fetchData(scanRequest) {
        let deferred = $.Deferred()

        this.xhr = $.ajax({
            url: this.#ajaxApiBaseUrl + '/scan',
            method: "POST",
            data: data,
            dataType: "json"
        })
        .done((posts) => {
            deferred.resolve(posts)
        })
        .fail(() => {
            deferred.reject()
        })

        return deferred
    }

    stopFetchData() {
        console.log('stopScan')
        console.log(this.xhr)
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the class `getPostDataController`?

Comment: const controller = new getPostDataController(); controller. fetchData()

Comment: `$.ajax()` returns a Deferred instance; there is no need to make another one. Also how are you calling `stopFetchData`?

Comment: Also note that you call your constructor with no argument, so initially `this.xhr` will be `undefined` (until you call `fetchData()`).  Thus if you call `stopFetchData()` *before* you have started a fetch, xhr will not be set. If you call `stopFetchData()` using the same controller instance (`controller.fetchData()`) then it should work.

Comment: Oh man! Thank you so much! I created a new controller() so it can't access the var. So easy.. :D